# Lsyncd Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am setting up lsyncd at for automatic sync local and remote folders. I have researched for many solution available, also adding extra params to the conf file.
I have also, updated the sshd_config with `PermitRootLogin without-password`

Also, I am able to ssh with password and also rsync without password manually tried but the problem is when I use it via lsyncd it give permission denied error 3 times and exit (seems like its asking for password).

lsyncd.conf.lua file

```
settings {
        logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
        statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
        statusInterval = 10
}
sync {
    default.rsync,
    source="/home/gaurav/Desktop/source/",
    target="root@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/root/destination/",
    rsync = {
        compress = true,
        acls = true,
        verbose = true,
        _extra = {"-P", "-e", "/usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -i /home/gaurav/.ssh/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"}
    }
}
```

Also tried with this one also.

```
settings = {
    logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status"
}

sync {
    default.rsyncssh,
    source = "/home/gaurav/Desktop/source/",
    host = "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
    targetdir = "/root/destination/"
}
```

Logs

```
Sun Dec  7 17:18:09 2014 Normal: recursive startup rsync: /home/gaurav/Desktop/source/ -> root@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/root/destination/
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
Sun Dec  7 17:18:12 2014 Error: Temporary or permanent failure on startup of "/home/gaurav/Desktop/source/". Terminating since "insist" is not set.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu 12.04 you must use rsyncOps instead rsync = {} block.

Try this:

```
sync { 
  default.rsync, 
  source="/var/www/",
  target=server..":/var/www/",
  excludeFrom="/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd-excludes.txt",
  rsyncOps={"-e", "/usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-avz"}
}
```

https://www.stephenrlang.com/2015/12/how-to-install-and-configure-lsyncd/